# php laravel update if only column field is null

Tags: php, sql, laravel, isnull

Sql query

```
    UPDATE MyTable 
SET 
        Field1 = IsNull(@Field1, Field1),
        Field2 = IsNull(@Field2, Field2),
        Field3 = IsNull(@Field3, Field3)
WHERE 
     field4 = 1234
```

How can i write this code in laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

You COULD use a [raw statement](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries).

**Example**

```
DB::statement("UPDATE MyTable SET Field1 = IsNull(@Field1, Field1), WHERE field4 = 1234");
```

There might be a smoother solution (using eloquent) in Laravel for this, but this works.

Comment: I will try this. Thanks